# Take Result Mysql assign PHP variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

When I do a mysql select statement, I get the below when echo'ing $result;

```
echo $row['comment2'];
```

Gives me this:

```
$fullname = ddasdfd; 
$bacc = 324234234; 
$brouting = 23423434; 
$btype = checking; 
$btype2 = personal; 
$bankname = 234234234;
```

How do I use that result that I got when select a text field inside my mysql table and assign it to php variables so I can do:

```
echo $fullname;
```

Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

Current code:

```
$query = "select * FROM `store`.`oc_order` WHERE `order_status_id`='10' AND `achgroup`='' ORDER BY `date_added` LIMIT 10"; 
  $result = mysql_query($query,$db) or die(mysql_error());
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  echo $row['comment2'];
```

I want when echo'ing ddasdfd:

Comment: paste your current code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While most obvious way would be something that involves [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval) - I strongly recommend you to avoid that. It's completely unsafe.

Thus, you can resolve your case with some regex stuff and [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract) results:

```
$result='$fullname=ddasdfd; $bacc=324234234; $brouting=23423434; $btype=checking; $btype2=personal; $bankname=234234234;';
preg_match_all('/\$([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)\s*\=\s*([^;]*);/ms', $result, $matches);
$matches = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
extract($matches); //now $fullname, $bacc and so on are in global scope
```

Note, that:

- It will *not* check syntax. Yes, it *will* fail if syntax isn't correct
- It will *not* check if variables have valid names
- It will *not* check if values are "good" (so delimiter is `;`)

And, in fact, it shouldn't do that (because regex isn't thing that may or should be used for such issues). To say more, as more correct way I see normalization of your initial data somehow that you will avoid things like this - i.e. dealing with parsing/executing PHP code.

Comment: Is there anyway we can remove any odd characters within the results... I noticed that if I have $fullname=dasdddf&adfsdfd - then the code acts up....

Comment: What characters are 'odd' and where?

Answer (score 1):

If your $result variable contains a string with var_name = value separated by \n then you can do :

```
$results = explode('\n', $results);
foreach ($results as $result){
    eval($result);
}

echo $fullname;
```

Pay attention though, eval can lead to important security issues.
Don't eval untrusted data.

Answer (score 0):

Not having seen your code, it should look something like this:

```
$resultsArray = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$fullname = $resultsArray['fullname'];
$brouting = $resultsArray['brouting']; 
$btype = $resultsArray['btype']; 
$btype2 = $resultsArray['btype2']; 
$bankname = $resultsArray['bankname'];
```

From here you should be able to echo the variables freely.